# Is there a way to modify my code to be able to create a LED blinker that synchs with the time of the code that is ran?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno, led

I currently have a Raspberry Pi and a Arduino Uno which are connected to one another. On the Raspberry Pi 3b, I have a python code that creates a CSV file that measures the Shunt voltage,bus voltage, power, and current ( Using a INA219 sensor that is connected to it) in which is stored within the CSV file that is created from the code. On the Arduino Uno, I have a LED connected to it via breadboard and it is blinking by a basic code ( to be sure that it works).

I am trying to modify the code below so that I can measure the data alongside the CSV to run for only 3 minutes but dont know how to do that. As of right now, the CSV file runs endlessly until it is stopped by the user. I also want to blink the LED in the Arduino in which it corresponds to the measure of the Pi. I have five runs that I would like to do. I would like to do 1Hz, 5Hz, 10Hz,50Hz, and 100Hz. So for example, If we are using the 100 Hz and would run that within the code. That would be 100*60*3 (due to the 3 minutes that it needs to run for), with that the LED should blink 18,000 times as of running this. Obviously this would be far to fast for the human eye to see but I am just having a problem with making this happen. Would anyone be able to help? The code is below in which I am referring to, is there anything else that you would suggest I do? I already have done the set-up for the raspberry pi and the Arduino uno to communicate.

```
    #Importing libraries
import csv
import time

from ina219 import INA219
from ina219 import DeviceRangeError


SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1

read_ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS) 
read_ina.configure()

  
def read_all():
    
    data = {}
    data['Bus Voltage'] = read_ina.voltage()
    data['Bus Current'] = read_ina.current()
    data['Power'] = read_ina.power()
    data['Shunt Voltage'] = read_ina.shunt_voltage()
    data['Frequency'] = 0
    return data

    
with open('SensorData.csv', 'w') as f:
    data = read_all()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,
                            fieldnames = list (data.keys()))

    writer.writeheader()

    
    exit = False

    while not exit:
        try:
            writer.writerow(data)
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            data = read_all()
            data.start()
            compute_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            data['Frequency'] = 1 / compute_time
            
            time.sleep(10) 
            data.terminate()
            
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit = True
```

Comment: 1) One question at a time.  2) You described your wish list, but you didn't show your effort of doing it, and the problem you are facing.

Comment: Well Please read and dissect I know that there are about two questions. I have showed my code and I need help. I normally wont go on this forum unless I really feel lost. I am simply asking for guidance for someone that is willing to help.